# 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, class-library

I have 3 projects in my solution which basically does the addition of two numbers and returns the value to the client. I want to accomplish a callback from service to client with this simple project in WCF.

> 1. C# console app which acts as a client which calls WCF service library by providing the 2 values to be added.
> 2. WCF Service library which is the service, calls the C# class library to do the addition.
> 3. C# class library which is being called by the WCF service library for adding the two values, it does the work of adding the two values and returns the value to the WCF service library and WCF Service library returns the value to the C# Console app.
>
> Also the configuration of the WCF service interface and the WCF service class which implements the interface are like this

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession) ServiceContract[(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required.)]
```

> When a client that is C# console app calls the WCF service and if the WCF service does the addition and returns to the console app, my project works fine.
>
> If Client calls service and in turn service calls a C# class library for computing addition it gives me “System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException occurred in mscorlib.dll”.
>
> The way the WCF service calls C# class library is by creating an instance of the C# class library inside the method which is being called by console app and using that instance to call the method of that library.
>
> I think I need to hook up the session somehow. Correct me if I am wrong, So it will not make the communication object to a faulted state. But I don’t know how to do it. Else any other ideas are also really appreciated. Thank you everyone in advance.
>
> Client.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp
{
// The service contract is defined in generatedClient.cs, generated from the service by the svcutil tool.

// Define class which implements callback interface of duplex contract
public class CallbackHandler : ICalculatorDuplexCallback
{
    public void Result(double result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result({0})", result);
    }

    public void Equation(string eqn)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Equation({0})", eqn);
    }
}

class Client
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Construct InstanceContext to handle messages on callback interface
        InstanceContext instanceContext = new InstanceContext(new CallbackHandler());

        // Create a client with given client endpoint configuration
        CalculatorDuplexClient client = new CalculatorDuplexClient(instanceContext);

        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate client once the output is displayed.");
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Call the AddTo service operation.
        double value = 102.00D;
        client.AddTo(value);

        // Call the SubtractFrom service operation.
        value = 50.00D;
        client.SubtractFrom(value);

        // Call the MultiplyBy service operation.
        value = 17.65D;
        client.MultiplyBy(value);

        // Call the DivideBy service operation.
        value = 2.00D;
        client.DivideBy(value);
        client.Addition(5, 9);
        client.serviceadd(5, 6, 3);

        // Complete equation
        client.Clear();

        Console.ReadLine();

        //Closing the client gracefully closes the connection and cleans up resources
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

}

> Generatedclient.cs

```
namespace Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp
{
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]

[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp", ConfigurationName="Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp.ICalculatorDuplex", CallbackContract=typeof(Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp.ICalculatorDuplexCallback), SessionMode=System.ServiceModel.SessionMode.Required)]
     public interface ICalculatorDuplex
    {
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp/ICalculatorDuplex/Clear")]
    void Clear();

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp/ICalculatorDuplex/AddTo")]
    void AddTo(double n);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp/ICalculatorDuplex/SubtractFrom")]
    void SubtractFrom(double n);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp/ICalculatorDuplex/MultiplyBy")]
    void MultiplyBy(double n);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp/ICalculatorDuplex/DivideBy")]
    void DivideBy(double n);
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay = true, Action = "http://Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp/ICalculatorDuplex/Addition")]
    void Addition(double a, double b);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay = true, Action = "http://Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp/ICalculatorDuplex/serviceadd")]
    void serviceadd(double a, double b, double c);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface ICalculatorDuplexCallback
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp/ICalculatorDuplex/Result")]
    void Result(double result);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp/ICalculatorDuplex/Equation")]
    void Equation(string eqn);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface ICalculatorDuplexChannel : Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp.ICalculatorDuplex, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class CalculatorDuplexClient : System.ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase<Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp.ICalculatorDuplex>, Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp.ICalculatorDuplex
{

    public CalculatorDuplexClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance) : 
            base(callbackInstance)
    {
    }

    public CalculatorDuplexClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance, string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(callbackInstance, endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

    public CalculatorDuplexClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance, string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(callbackInstance, endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public CalculatorDuplexClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance, string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(callbackInstance, endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public CalculatorDuplexClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(callbackInstance, binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        base.Channel.Clear();
    }

    public void AddTo(double n)
    {
        base.Channel.AddTo(n);
    }

    public void SubtractFrom(double n)
    {
        base.Channel.SubtractFrom(n);
    }

    public void MultiplyBy(double n)
    {
        base.Channel.MultiplyBy(n);
    }

    public void DivideBy(double n)
    {
        base.Channel.DivideBy(n);
    }
    public void Addition(double a, double b)
    {
        base.Channel.Addition(a,b);
    }
    public void serviceadd(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        base.Channel.serviceadd(a, b, c);
    }

}
```

}

> WCF Service.cs

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp
{
// Define a duplex service contract.
// A duplex contract consists of two interfaces.
// The primary interface is used to send messages from client to service.
// The callback interface is used to send messages from service back to client.
// ICalculatorDuplex allows one to perform multiple operations on a running result.
// The result is sent back after each operation on the ICalculatorCallback interface.
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.Samples.DualHttp", SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed,
                 CallbackContract = typeof(ICalculatorDuplexCallback))]
public interface ICalculatorDuplex
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Clear();
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void AddTo(double n);
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SubtractFrom(double n);
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void MultiplyBy(double n);
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void DivideBy(double n);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Addition(double a, double b);


    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void serviceadd(double a, double b, double c);

}
// The callback interface is used to send messages from service back to client.
// The Result operation will return the current result after each operation.
// The Equation opertion will return the complete equation after Clear() is called.
public interface ICalculatorDuplexCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Result(double result);
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Equation(string eqn);
}

// Service class which implements a duplex service contract.
// Use an InstanceContextMode of PerSession to store the result
// An instance of the service will be bound to each duplex session
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorDuplex
{
    double result;
    string equation;
    ICalculatorDuplexCallback callback = null;

    public CalculatorService()
    {
        result = 0.0D;
        equation = result.ToString();
        callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICalculatorDuplexCallback>();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        callback.Equation(equation + " = " + result.ToString());
        result = 0.0D;
        equation = result.ToString();
    }

    public void AddTo(double n)
    {
        result += n;
        equation += " + " + n.ToString();
        callback.Result(result);
    }

    public void SubtractFrom(double n)
    {
        result -= n;
        equation += " - " + n.ToString();
        callback.Result(result);
    }

    public void MultiplyBy(double n)
    {
        result *= n;
        equation += " * " + n.ToString();
        callback.Result(result);
    }

    public void DivideBy(double n)
    {
        result /= n;
        equation += " / " + n.ToString();
        callback.Result(result);
    }
    public void Addition(double a, double b)
    {
        double c = a + b;
        callback.Result(c);
    }
 public void serviceadd(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        CSharpClassLibrary.Class1 object1 = new CSharpClassLibrary.Class1();
       double d= object1.add(5, 6, 3);

        callback.Result(d);
    }

}
    }
```

'  CsharpClasslibrary.cs

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
     namespace CSharpClassLibrary
     {
       public class Class1
           {
               public double add(double a, double b, double c)
                 {
                    return a + b+ c;
                 }
           }         
     }
```

> the method which causes the problem is "serviceadd".

Comment: Please add the fragment of you code that throws the exception where you are creating your wcf client and closing it.

Comment: I have added all the projects, The method which cause the problem is "servicadd" method. please look in to it and help me. I would really appreciate the help.